# Change Author template in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, javadoc

I want to change the automatic author that appears when I create a file in AndroidStudio.

```
/**
 * Created by a556520 on 16/01/14.
 */
public class POI {
```

The author takes 'a556520' but I want that appears my name, and not the number of employee. Is that possible?
I didn't find in the settings.

Answer (score 432, accepted):

You can overwrite the `${USER}` variable in the template file with the

```
#set( $VARIABLE = "value")
```

function. Go to **Settings** -> **Editor** -> **File and Code Templates** -> **Includes** -> **File Header** prepend the `#set()` function call, for example:

```
#set( $USER = "Your name" )
/**
* Created by ${USER} on ${DATE}.
*/
```

Comment: Thanks to all, I will take this question as "accepted" just because I fell that is more.. "cleaner". But all are Ok.

Thanks!

Comment: Here you could find a full [Doc](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/creating-and-editing-file-templates.html) on the topic

Comment: Is there any way I can apply it to the classes or files that I already created?

Comment: Is there a way to do this on a per project basis?

Answer (score 104):

The above answers are correct. But you can go even further and define your own variables - such as User, Company, Email etc.:

```
#set ($USER = "Name name")
#set ($COMPANY = "company Ltd")
#set ($EMAIL = "example@gmail.com")

/**
 * Created by ${USER} on ${DATE}.
 * ${COMPANY}
 * ${EMAIL}
 */
```

Answer (score 76):

**To edit your File Header template, do the following:**

1)Open Android Studio `Preferences` dialog.

2)In the search box, write "File and Code Templates".

3)Select the left menu item "File and Code Templates".

4)From the middle tabular navigation section, select `Includes`.

5)Select `File Header` item that applies to the Java files.

6)You will find an editor section that allow you to edit it for the required pattern. Use the description section below to understand the different parameters that can be used.

```
/**
* Created by ${USER} on ${DAY},${MONTH_NAME_FULL},${YEAR}
*/
```

[image]

Note: For the `name` attribute, you can simply write it directly without using attributes. Also you can add your company name or project name in the same way also such as:

```
/**
* Created by Sami on ${DAY},${MONTH_NAME_FULL},${YEAR}
* ABCDFG company,
* Dubai, UAE.
*/
```

Answer (score 22):

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> then go to **File and Code Templates**. Here you can set up what you want. E.g. replace `${USER}` to your name.

Answer (score 9):

Actually the correct way to change the username is to change the name
of the current user logged in into Windows. (if you're using windows)

Android Studio uses the name saved in %USERNAME% variable.
This is the name you get if you type `whoami` into a command console
or batch file. And it is the name that is stored under C(orWhatEver):\User.

To change the name you can **not** just change the name of the profile 
you are logged in. 
You need to create a new user and give it the correct name.
This way, even if you reinstall AndroidStudio some day, you will end with
the correct `${USER}` again.

The easier way surely is to just hard code your name into the template.
But that is just treating the symptoms and you should use the way to fix the root cause.

Comment: Perfect answer, but, not always you can create or change the %USERNAME&, in my case, when I asked it, It was, because I got a Work computer, where my "username" was my loggin id in the company (aXXXXX), and can't create new user ^^. But as you said, if you have the change to change USERNAME or create new account, will be better. Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

Settings -> Editor -> File and Code Templates -> Includes -> File Header

```
/**
 * @Author: yourname
 * @Date: ${DATE}
 */
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

You can change template for file header by going to  Preferences -> Editor -> File and Code Templates. Then change `${USER}` in File Header under Includes tab. However this is hardcoding solution it would be better to change actual value of `${USER}` variable.

Answer (score 3):

- Open Android Studio Preferences dialog.
- In the search box, write "File and Code Templates".
- Select the left menu item "File and Code Templates".
- From the middle tabular navigation section, select Includes.
- Select File Header item that applies to the Java files.
- You will find an editor section that allow you to edit it for the required pattern. Use the description section below to understand the different parameters that can be used.
- Set the properties first.
  `#set ($USER = "Your name")`
  `#set ($COMPANY = "Your company")`
  `#set ($EMAIL = "Your email")`

  /**`Created by ${USER} on ${DAY},${MONTH_NAME_FULL},${YEAR} ${COMPANY} ${EMAIL}` **/