# is there a way to bulk comment a header in each of the activities\ classes generated in android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

Is there a way to do a shortcut or something that puts a Comment's header, in each of the Classes and Activities 
like this header for example:

```
/*----------------------------------------------------------------
 *  Author:        Kevin Wayne
 *  Written:       5/3/1997
 *  Last updated:  8/7/2006
```

Or Other Headers in that style ?

Comment: Does this help - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21160288/change-author-template-in-android-studio ?

Comment: possible of duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/a/20109692/5515371

Comment: it seems a duplicate...but how get the third line updated?

Comment: usually `Last updated` is based on a version control system (GIT, TFS, SVN...) which a trace of file can be kept and retrieved ?