# How to force Android Studio to generate the documentation with the developer's correct name

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea

When I create a new class in `Android Studio`, it automatically generates description above the class as in the following example:

```
/**
* Created by Tomas on 12.08.2016.
*/
```

Actually the name `Android Studio` uses in the automatically generated doc, which according to the above example is "Tomas", is not correct.

My question is, how to force `Android Studio` to generate the documentation of the class with my correct name?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change Author template in Android Studio](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21160288/change-author-template-in-android-studio)

Comment: your question is the same with [Change Author template in Android Studio](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21160288/change-author-template-in-android-studio)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Press `Ctrl+Alt+S` and go to `Settings -> Editor -> File and Code Templates -> Includes -> File Header` and do the changes.

```
 /**
 * Created by ${USER} on ${DATE}.
 */
```

Answer (score 1):

Press `Ctrl+Alt+S` then go to File and Code Templates.

E.g. replace `${USER}` to your name.